# Adding an "Apps you can add" app with Powershell for SharePoint Online for all Subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Currently I am running into an issue. I have an app installed from the SharePoint store "Docusign" and it is at the top level site collection. I have to manually go to every subsite and click the gear and choose add an app, then choose docusign and then click Trust It. I want to enable this "app" on all the subsites of said site collection with a Powershell script/command.

**Site Collection 1** Where app was initially added

- Subsite1
- Subsite2
- ....etc

I am very new to powershell and I have tried to copy and paste some scripts together to get this to work but keep hitting a wall. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated or should I approach this a different way? Tried reaching out to Docusign support but that was a dead end as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

What I ended up doing was creating a powershell that ran through the list of sites via a csv file, then opened up the add an app page, added the app, then trusted it. It was a client side powershell that had to run on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago we faced with this issue.
Our programmer said that he didn't find a solution for it.

I decide to write a little programm that open all sites in a browser and it is clicking "Trust It" automatically.